# The libman package manager freezes in initialization

Tags: visual-studio, package-managers, libman

I used the libman package manager on Visual Studio 2022 very well, however, the libman freezes in package console manager for a long time today when I use the `libman init` command.

The libman --version works well.

```
PM> libman --version

2.1.161+abc97ecc7d.RR
```

I found the similar problem in the [Visual Studio community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/libman-hangs-in-1593/400493) but it didn't have any solutions or workarounds.

I clean the cache of libman by below command, however, the issue doesn't resolve.

```
PM> libman cache clean
Cache cleaned.

PM> libman clean
libman : libman.json was not  `found:C:\Users\user\source\repos\BlazorServerTestDynamicAccess\libman.json`
```

What can I do to resolve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to work around this:

1. Use a different console.  As mentioned in the VS Developer Community issue:

> But the Package Manager Console isn't a real command line, and doesn't provide the ability for a program to read input.

2. Avoid any prompts for user input.  For `libman init`, add the `-y` or `--useDefault` parameter.  For `libman install`, make sure you have provided the provider name and destination path libman.json file (using the `defaultProvider` and `defaultDestination` properties), or as parameters (see `libman install --help`).

Comment: Thank you so much. The `-y` switch solved my problem.